# How can I fix a sexbot?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I am doing the atomic wrangler 'escort' quest. I found all 3 targets easily due to the markers, but the sexbot is in a vat of sorts. Accessing the computer next to it seems to indicate that I can upload a routine to it. How or where do i obtain this routine? I searched the building itself and only found one locked locker which gave me a card but doesn't grant me any things to upload to the robot.

Comment: Yes, everyone is always fixing the sexbot for someone else. Sure you are! ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a high enough **Science skill** (60 upwards) you can program the bot yourself using the terminal you have already discovered.

Alternately, you need to get a holotape with a program on, which can be obtained from **Ralph** at **Mick & Ralph's**. Depending on your speech skill this may cost you some caps (a maximum of 150). Once Ralph has agreed, you will need to leave and come back later (after a game day, I believe). Then take the holotape to the terminal next to the bot and install.

The key card you have found is used to obtain access to the terminal without hacking, it's provided so that players without the relevant skill can still complete the mission. Since you've already gained access to the terminal, it is useless.

[Here's](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Wang_Dang_Atomic_Tango#Detailed_walkthrough) the quest page at the Fallout Wikia, which provides more detail should it be required.

Comment: the link gives me a 'URL Blocked by policy' the main reason i need to ask questions here. Thanks for giving me the answer in your reply,  my science being 52, i need one level or a magazine and i can finish the quest.

Comment: @Andy: You don't have to answer, but who's doing the filtering? Your workplace, your ISP, the government?

Comment: @Andy - Once you get your science up to 60 you should be able to get by that "URL Blocked by policy" filter no problem.... or you could use the proxy key card.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm Or parents, perhaps?